Relation between real and complex algebra representations and induced real structures
Assume we have a real algebra $A_\mathbb{R}$ which is embedded in the complex algebra $A_\mathbb{C} \stackrel \sim = A_\mathbb{R} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ (Algebra isomorphism given by $\Phi$) such that $A_\mathbb{R}$ has a unique real irreducible algebra representation $S_\mathbb{R}$ and $A_\mathbb{C}$ a unique complex irrep $S_\mathbb{C}$ up to equivalence. We also know that $dim_\mathbb{R}(S_\mathbb{R}) = dim_\mathbb{C}(S_\mathbb{C})$.
Now, are the following assertions correct?

$S_\mathbb{R} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ is an algebra representation of     $A_\mathbb{C}$.
Representation given by: $\rho_{A_\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{C}}(a \otimes \lambda) := \rho_\mathbb{R} (a) \otimes \lambda$, $\:\:$ $\rho_{A_\mathbb{C}}:=     \rho_{A_\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{C}} \circ \Phi$

$S_\mathbb{R} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ and $S_\mathbb{C}$ are equivalent representations
Both have the same complex dimension and $S_\mathbb{C}$ is the unique irreducible algebra representation. We will denote the equivariant vector space isomorphism by $\Psi$.

The restriction of the representation $S_\mathbb{C}$ onto $A_\mathbb{R}$ has a real structure $\mathcal{J}: S_\mathbb{C} \to S_\mathbb{C}$ ($A_\mathbb{R}$-equivariant antilinear involution).
Given by: $\mathcal{J}_{S_\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{C}}(s \otimes \lambda) := s \otimes \bar \lambda$, $\:\:$ $\mathcal{J} := \Psi \circ \mathcal{J}_{S_\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{C}} \circ \Psi^{-1}$


If this is true, this in particular means that the real algebra $Mat(n,n; \mathbb{H})$ ($\mathbb{H}$: Quaternions), which is embedded in the complex algebra $Mat(2n,2n; \mathbb{C})$, induces a complex representation of the real algebra and a real structure. This in turn implies that there are Majorana spinors in spacetimes of signature $p-q = 2 \: mod \: 8$ which is certainly not true. There should only be a pseudo-real structure, not a real one.
